# Issue with d3.4.4.0 and lightning locker service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, locker-service, d3

> I used the below code to implement collapsible tree chart using d3.js. The same code works fine with lockerservice off. With lockerservice on the tree chart is not working. What I have found is the parent node is appended as 'g' with lockerservice off. But when it is on it is appended as just an object so in selectAll function doesn't return the parent node. Any work around for this issue??

```
<!-- controller -->
afterscriptsloaded : function( component, event, helper ) {
    console.log('!!!!!!!!');
    var treeData =
              {
                "name": "Top Level",
                "children": [
                  { 
                    "name": "Level 2: A",
                    "children": [
                      { "name": "Son of A" },
                      { "name": "Daughter of A" }
                    ]
                  },
                  { "name": "Level 2: B" }
                ]
              };

            // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
            var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
                width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            // append the svg object to the body of the page
            // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
            // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin

            var treeChart = component.find("treeChart").getElement(); 
            var svg = d3.select(treeChart).append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate("
                      + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            var i = 0,
                duration = 750,
                root, path;

            // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
            var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);
            console.log('treemap === ', treemap);
            // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
            root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
            root.x0 = height / 2;
            root.y0 = 0;

            console.log('-- root- --', root);

            // Collapse after the second level
            root.children.forEach(collapse);

            update(root);

            // Collapse the node and all it's children
            function collapse(d) {
              if(d.children) {
                d._children = d.children
                d._children.forEach(collapse)
                d.children = null
              }
            }

            function update(source) {

               console.log('---- source ----', source);

              // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
              var treeData = treemap(root);

              // Compute the new tree layout.
              var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
                  links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

              // Normalize for fixed-depth.
              nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

              // ****************** Nodes section ***************************
              console.log('-svg.selectAll-',svg.selectAll('g.node'));
              // Update the nodes...
              var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
                  .data(nodes, function(d) {
                      console.log('---- d.id -----', d.id,  d);
                      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                  });

              console.log('- node -', node);
              // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
              var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
                  .attr('class', 'node')
                  .attr("transform", function(d) {
                      console.log(' node enter ', source.y0, source.x0, d);
                    return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                })
                .on('click', click);

              // Add Circle for the nodes
              nodeEnter.append('circle')
                  .attr('class', 'node')
                  .attr('r', 1e-6)
                  .style("fill", function(d) {
                      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                  });

              // Add labels for the nodes
              nodeEnter.append('text')
                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                  .attr("x", function(d) {
                      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
                  })
                  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                  })
                  .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

              // UPDATE
              var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

              // Transition to the proper position for the node
              nodeUpdate.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { 
                    console.log('--- nodeupdate transition', d.y, d.x);
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                 });

              // Update the node attributes and style
              nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
                .attr('r', 10)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                })
                .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


              // Remove any exiting nodes
              var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr("transform", function(d) {
                      console.log('--- nodeexit ---', source.y, source.x);
                      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                  })
                  .remove();

              // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
              nodeExit.select('circle')
                .attr('r', 1e-6);

              // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
              nodeExit.select('text')
                .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

              // ****************** links section ***************************

              // Update the links...
              var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
                  .data(links, function(d) { 
                      console.log('--- link d', d);
                      return d.id; 
                  });

              // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
              var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
                  .attr("class", "link")
                  .attr('d', function(d){
                    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
                    console.log('--- link o', o);
                    return diagonal(o, o)
                  });

              // UPDATE
              var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

              // Transition back to the parent element position
              linkUpdate.transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr('d', function(d){ 
                      console.log('--- link d d', d);
                      return diagonal(d, d.parent) 
                  });

              // Remove any exiting links
              var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr('d', function(d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
                    return diagonal(o, o)
                  })
                  .remove();

              // Store the old positions for transition.
              nodes.forEach(function(d){
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
              });

              // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
              function diagonal(s, d) {

                path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
                        C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
                          ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
                          ${d.y} ${d.x}`
                console.log('--- path ---', path);
                return path
              }

              // Toggle children on click.
              function click(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                  } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                  }
                update(d);
              }
  }


 <!-- component -->.
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" access="global"> 
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.d3}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterscriptsloaded}" />


<div> 
    <div id="treeChart" aura:id="treeChart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I find that nodeUpdate.transition() is not updating the transform value

Comment: There's a high likelyhood this is fixed in Summer '17. There are similar posts about this library.